# Validation Rule Question - Required Fields

Tags: validation-rule, picklist

Hoping someone can help me figure out my validation rule. I'm pretty new to writing code so any help is appreciated. I want my rule to state: If the picklist value is soft closed or closed then to require the two additional fields. When testing this rule it works if the status is closed but not for soft closed. What am I missing?

```
(
    ISPICKVAL(Status, "Soft Closed")
    ||
    ISPICKVAL(Status, "Closed")
)
&&
(
    ISPICKVAL(Product_Area__c, "" )
    ||
    ISPICKVAL(Sub_Area__c, "" )
)
```

Comment: Looks fine to me. Are Product Area and Sub Area both picklist fields? Is "Soft Closed" the API name for that picklist value?

Comment: `ISPICKVAL()` is not case-sensitive, so that can't be the issue. The first thing I would look at is to confirm the actual values of your picklist (i.e. check to make sure that you really do have a `Soft Closed` value, with that exact spelling and a single space between the two words).

Comment: OMG!! I gues i was staring at it to long to realize i had "Soft Closed" and it should have been "Soft Close". Its all fixed! TYSM!!